# Connect MatLab to a web page

Tags: html, matlab, connection

I want to connect MATLAB to a [web page](https://genecodis.genyo.es/) . What I want to do is select organism name, select the annotations, paste my list of genes in textbox number 3 and submit! then I save the results (all automatically).
Is this even possible?

Comment: I guess you will need the Java Robot class, as described in the [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/gui-automation-robot) blog.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach would be to have a [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) in the web page, upon [submitting form data](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) a [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) script is run by the web server, and this script may in turn [call Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html). Or the script itself may be written in Matlab. The output of the script would then be the result web page. To do something like this you need admin access to the web server, know about CGI programming and HTML generation.